# Move text from side of image to below image

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image

I want to move the title of the posts under the thumbnail of the post while keepi. This seems like a fairly easy thing to do, but I can't figure out the correct coding. If anyone could help I would really appreciate it.

image of what it looks like (I want the post title below the image thumbnail)
[image]

related-posts.php

```html
<div class="related-posts">
<?php $orig_post = $post;
global $post;
$categories = get_the_category($post->ID);
if ($categories) {
$category_ids = array();
foreach($categories as $individual_category) $category_ids[] = $individual_category->term_id;
$args=array(
'category__in' => $category_ids,
'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
'posts_per_page'=> 3, // Number of related posts that will be shown.
'caller_get_posts'=>1
);
$my_query = new wp_query( $args );
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
echo '<div id="related-posts"><h3 class="related-posts-title">Related Posts</h3><ul>';
while( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
$my_query->the_post();?>
<div class="relatedthumb"><a href="<? the_permalink()?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><span class="related-posts-image"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></span></a></div>
<div class="relatedcontent">
<h3><a href="<? the_permalink()?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
</div>


<?
}
echo '</ul></div>';
}
}
$post = $orig_post;
wp_reset_query(); ?>
</div>
```

css

```html
.related-posts-title {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.related-posts-image img {
        height:259px;
    width:400px;

}
.relatedthumb {
    display: inline-block;
}
.relatedcontent {
display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would wrap the image and the title together in a div and apply the in-line styling to the outside div only.

Answer (score 0):

if you set the image to a block element it should take up the rest of the page and move the text below it.  Then its just a matter of using padding and margin to move it where you want it.